# Preload The Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

I want to create a preloader of my full page.

```
<body>
<div id="preload-content">Please wait</div>
<div id="body-container" style="background-image:url(very-big-image-file.jpg);">
// page contents goes here
</div>
</body>
```

now i have a huge image in my #body-container.
i use jQuery and when i use .ready() function page appears but images are still loading.

```
$("body").ready(function() {
    $("#preload-content").delay(500).fadeOut(400, function() {
        $("#body-container").fadeIn(200);
        $("body").css("background-color","#fff").css("color","#000");
    });
});
```

$(document).ready() is not working either.
i want to show #body-container after all images, plugins, scripts, css files loaded succesfully!
so... how can i do this.

Comment: The image will load on a separate thread. So, it will not affect the ready() function.

Answer (score 1):

You can try.

```
        $("body").ready(function() {

       // Create a image object 
        var bgImage = new Image();

        // bind loading event
        $(bgImage).bind("onload",function(){

            // Set the background css
            $("#body-container").css('background-image','url(very-big-image-file.jpg)');

            // Fade your preloader content
            $("#preload-content").delay(500).fadeOut(400, function() {
                $("#body-container").fadeIn(200);
                $("body").css("background-color","#fff").css("color","#000");
            });
        });

        //Start loading your image
        bgImage.src = "very-big-image-file.jpg";

        });
```

Apologize for some typo error. But the concept is like that.

Comment: but what can i do if i have more big images on my page? do i have to bind all images onload function to each other?

Comment: Yeah, you can create a preloader function which input a array of imge's path which you want to preload. But i don't think it is good to preload a large amount of image before the page display.

Answer (score 1):

When you call [`$("anything").ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) it all goes to the same place (and event handler when the DOM is ready, not necessarily all resources), the selector actually doesn't matter.

What you want here though is `window.onload`, which fires when images have loaded as well, like this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#preload-content").delay(500).fadeOut(400, function() {
        $("#body-container").fadeIn(200);
        $("body").css("background-color","#fff").css("color","#000");
    });
});
```

Make sure this is *outside* of any `document.ready` handlers, as there's a chance the `onload` event already executed then.

Comment: yes, it works but if you dont have images on CSS... it only works on <img /> images...

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Include the heartcode canvasloader js file -->
    <script src="http://heartcode-canvasloader.googlecode.com/files/heartcode-canvasloader-min-0.9.1.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
        body, html {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            overflow:hidden;
            background-color:#353535;
        }
        .wrapper {
            position:absolute;
            top:50%;
            left:50%;
        }
            #contenedor {
                    background-color: #fff;
            }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body onLoad="document.getElementById('precarga').style.visibility='hidden';document.getElementById('contenedor').style.visibility='visible';" >

        <div id="precarga" style="visibility: visible">
            <!-- Create a div which will be the canvasloader wrapper -->    
    <div id="canvasloader-container" class="wrapper"></div>

    <!-- This script creates a new CanvasLoader instance and places it in the wrapper div -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var cl = new CanvasLoader('canvasloader-container');
        cl.setColor('#9e9e9e'); // default is '#000000'
        cl.setShape('spiral'); // default is 'oval'
        cl.setDiameter(200); // default is 40
        cl.setDensity(160); // default is 40
        cl.setRange(1); // default is 1.3
                cl.setSpeed(1); // default is 2
        cl.setFPS(60); // default is 24
        cl.show(); // Hidden by default

        // This bit is only for positioning - not necessary
        var loaderObj = document.getElementById("canvasLoader");
        loaderObj.style.position = "absolute";
        loaderObj.style["top"] = cl.getDiameter() * -0.5 + "px";
        loaderObj.style["left"] = cl.getDiameter() * -0.5 + "px";
    </script>
        </div>

        <div id="contenedor" style="visibility: hidden">
            <!-- Modify this with your content [start] -->
            <p align="justify">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sit rhoncus tellus tristique ipsum, etiam enim commodo purus ligula, dui praesent vivamus fusce vel, justo vitae nesciunt suspendisse. Pretium elit maecenas mollis pellentesque, leo in vestibulum vitae habitasse dolor lacus, elit pharetra nec cras suspendisse, lectus eget nulla elit. Ut sapien velit quis accumsan nibh varius. Nunc maecenas, eu sapien porttitor convallis, nullam cras. Dolores mauris cum at velit, mauris posuere nunc euismod. Vel leo volutpat scelerisque aliquam mi.</p>
            <p align="justify">
                Aenean sed per nec in facilisis ullamcorper, mattis cras neque mauris fusce. Non odio gravida et, aliquet laoreet ac consequat risus, ut ridiculus sit massa est. A tristique adipiscing nulla, vel interdum magna. Luctus tincidunt curabitur erat ac, nisl praesent odio, in ullamcorper sem, proin tortor, dignissim feugiat orci non quam vitae mi. Id amet, vitae magna nunc velit vel, cras wisi tincidunt magnam at donec venenatis. Rutrum quis turpis eget. Nec quis donec sed non ultrices gravida, suscipit varius vivamus, velit libero quis imperdiet molestie.</p>
            <p align="justify">
                Pellentesque ornare eu lacus non, pede tempus velit duis, gravida nam phasellus sem, amet accumsan tincidunt wisi. Et libero et neque, aliquam pretium rerum neque, feugiat malesuada est sed autem a platea, lectus ultrices. Vitae tristique aliquet, tincidunt wisi velit odio sodales nunc nunc. Sed tincidunt turpis a nullam magna, sagittis vestibulum pellentesque integer montes neque, nunc odio neque diam lorem integer, sociis eu. Maecenas ut lectus senectus auctor dictum, ligula volutpat nulla pulvinar nam pellentesque pellentesque, vitae morbi magna dui in risus, aliquam vel mi odio purus duis suspendisse, justo mattis morbi integer. Pretium nec a, duis nunc mi, in vel. Lacus dui, eros nulla justo sollicitudin. Turpis et et pharetra non.</p>
            <p align="justify">
                Nunc maecenas turpis, vel in sed eget arcu, elit vitae. Curabitur et odio in ornare metus est. Massa porttitor consectetuer. Vitae bibendum, consectetuer duis diam quam in, est etiam aliquam enim molestie scelerisque. Vestibulum sed eros ac vitae lectus. A leo, quod volutpat id et lacus vitae vitae. Aenean tellus vivamus parturient metus, pellentesque ut lorem ut orci nisl. Ut et id luctus eros, feugiat in malesuada tellus quisque, iaculis tristique, nonummy massa voluptas vel. Elit a erat pulvinar sem sagittis, ligula eget est amet, a tristique ut ac wisi, gravida donec et eget nec. Amet nec, ut non penatibus eget, ornare purus sollicitudin a tincidunt vitae rutrum, commodo non faucibus, aut pretium risus lorem nulla egestas auctor.</p>
            <p align="justify">
            </p>
            <img src="http://v11.nonxt8.c.bigcache.googleapis.com/static.panoramio.com/photos/original/21785753.jpg?redirect_counter=1"/>
            <!-- Modify this with your content [end] -->
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```